# NServiceBus handler turning up with empty message when using JSON

Tags: c#, xml, json, nservicebus

I got a issue with NServiceBus 4.4.2, which has me stomped. I self host NSB inside a MVC application. The instance is put into an Autofac container and injected into the controllers. So far, so good.

Sending a message with SendLocal (a command) works as expected. The message turns up in MSMQ in JSON, as I have NSB configured to do so.

Now, my message handler is called, which is also part of my MVC app. For simplicity, I do not inject anything into this handler right now. In any case, the message, which turns up, is empty (e.g. properties are null or Guid.Empty).

When I change the serialization of NSB to XML, it works. It looks like, as if the same instance uses JSON for serialization und XML for deserialization.

Here is the code I use to initialize the Bus:

```
        Configure.Transactions.Enable();
        Configure.Serialization.Json();
        Configure.Features.Disable<Sagas>();
        Feature.Disable<XmlSerialization>();

        Instance =
            Configure.With(
                AllAssemblies.Matching("Messages1.dll").And("Handler1.dll").And("Messages2.dll").And("Handler2.dll"))
                .DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusEndpointName"])
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .Log4Net<RollingFileAppender>(x => x.File = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusLog"])
                .RavenSubscriptionStorage()
                .UseTransport<Msmq>()
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                .UnicastBus()
                .RunHandlersUnderIncomingPrincipal(false)
                .CreateBus()
                .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>()
                    .Install());
```

If have no clue what's going on here :-( Does anyone have an idea?

Kind regards
Marco Heine

Comment: I'm trying to debug into the NServiceBus Code to figure out, what's going on. Not much luck though, as it's not obvious. The only thing I found was, that I made a breakpoint on the XML Deserialization and JSON Deserialization methods. It seems, the JSON Version is never been called. When I change to XML, the Deserialization method is being called. Is there a bug in NSB 4.4.2?

Comment: Is it possible you had old (xml serialized) messages in the queue?

Comment: Sorry, nothing that obvious. I cleared the queue, changed to XML, made a new SendLocal and it works. Back to JSON, and it doesn't. I can see the JSON Message in the queue (using Queue Explorer). I spend more than 10 hours on this problem now. I uninstalled PostSharp to no avail. I'm trying now to downgrade to NSB 4.1. By the way, I'm running MVC 5.1. Might this be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help,

but as so often, the error lies between chair and keyboard :-/

Yes, all my observations were seemingly all correct, but for all the wrong reasons. The problem was simple: My message class had no parameterless constructor and only private setters. It seems, that while the XML-Serializer doesn't have a problem with this, the JSON serializer does.

After making the properties get / setters public, I finally get my message returned. Bummer.

Especially a big thank you towards Particular, who made a big effort in trying to help me. I guess, all I needed were a few days off =)

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problem. I completely forgot that messages don't just need to be serialized, but also deserialized. That can only happen if the framework can put values back into the properties it previously read. If I make it an immutable class, it wouldn't be able to put the values back into the correct properties.Why didn't I think of this before I read your post...

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing [NServiceBus.Autofac](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.Autofac/) in your solution?

Seems like the bus is configured to use two different containers and this is causing weird side effects.

```
   Instance =
        Configure.With(
            AllAssemblies.Matching("Messages1.dll").And("Handler1.dll").And("Messages2.dll").And("Handler2.dll"))
            .DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusEndpointName"])
            .DefaultBuilder()
```

NServiceBus has the Autofac merged into it. Calling `DefaultBuilder()` uses the internal container.

Have a read of their [documentation](http://docs.particular.net/NServiceBus/containers)

You basically need to call

`Configure.With.AutofacBuilder(pass container here)` and there's no need to register the instance returned from `Start()` function